# Recreate Visual Studio project file

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to deploy my first C# web app using Visual Studio 2013, and the web deployment package fails with the message

> `Error 43 Copying file Content\lib\bootstrap-timepicker\Gruntfile.js to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\Content\lib\bootstrap-timepicker\Gruntfile.js failed. Could not find file 'Content\lib\bootstrap-timepicker\Gruntfile.js.`

and the item itself displays

> `The item 'Gruntfile.js' does not exist in the project directory. It may have been moved, renamed, or deleted.`

when attempting to open it.  Gruntfile.js appears in numerous project folders, not just the one folder in which it carries the warning logo.

Where can I get a copy of just the bootstrap-timepicker Gruntfile.js, and how should it be imported into the project?  The "Getting Started" and "Installing Grunt" sections of the gruntjs website seem to only discuss the original acquiring of the product, not necessarily how to recreate a corrupted version.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: was bootstrap timepicker installed via nuget? If so you could try re-installing the nuget package

Comment: Thanks for the response ADyson!  Someone else set up the project, but I will check on that.

Comment: you can check easily by looking in the "Manage Nuget Packages" option for the project (right-click on the project file) - you don't need to ask the project creator.

Comment: Thanks again - the "Installed Packages" under "Manage Nuget Packages" shows a few jQuery files, but nothing to indicate Grunt or Gruntfile.js.

Comment: gruntfile.js is part of the "bootstrap timepicker" package (as suggested by the path you gave). That's what you want to be looking for in the list (or something similar).

Comment: Unfortunately, there doesn't appear to be anything relating to Twitter Bootstrap, Bootstrap, Timepicker, or Gruntfile.  Would downloading the Nuget package anyway still work?

Comment: no, unless it happens to try and download the files into the same location in your project and fix the issue. Judging from google (https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=bootrstrap%20timepicker%20gruntfile.js), it looks like there's a good chance it's this component: https://github.com/jdewit/bootstrap-timepicker so you could probably just download the gruntfile from there.

Comment: I saw that link, actually, but couldn't decide between it or this one: https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker.  Is there a way to tell?

Comment: I think you'd just have to compare the other files in the folder with what each of those libraries distributes in their output folder and see which one matches most closely. Unless there's a README or something else in there that gives it away

Comment: FWIW, `gruntfile.js` shouldn't be required to deploy your app, so your project shouldn't be trying to copy it in the first place.

Comment: @ADyson - It looks like the link you posted is the correct one.  After it's downloaded and unzipped, can I just right-click the project => Add => Reference and navigate to the unzipped file, or will that not overwrite the corrupted one?

Comment: @user1620220 - That's curious, because the only time the error pops up or seemingly has any effect is when it halts the deployment package creation.  What could be going on?

Comment: @jle just extract the gruntfile from the zip and put it in the location mentioned in your error message (`Content\lib\bootstrap-timepicker\`). Do the same for any other missing files. You can see what's missing in Visual Studio because the files will have a little yellow triangle next to them containing an exclamation mark. P.S. "Add Reference" is for adding references to compiled .NET DLLs, not for JS projects and the like.

Comment: @ADyson - Thanks for the info on Add Reference.  One last question that was, in part, what I was originally wondering: what's the best way to put that file in the location: through Visual Studio; copy from a Windows Explorer to the project's location; or another method?

Comment: yeah just copy it in Windows explorer. Nothing fancy required! If it's named as part of the project already, which it seems it probably is, Visual Studio will pick up that it's been added (or you can refresh the folder in the Solution Explorer view).

Comment: @ADyson - I think it worked!  If you wouldn't mind putting the link and the last comment in an answer, I'd be happy to mark it correct!

Comment: @jle - done, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's a file missing in one of your folders. And it looks like this component:  https://github.com/jdewit/bootstrap-timepicker

You can download the gruntfile.js from there, and (just using Windows Explorer) paste it into the folder location specified in the error message. If it's named as part of the project already Visual Studio will pick up that it's been added, or you can refresh the folder in the Solution Explorer view.

Do the same for any other missing files. You can see what's missing in Visual Studio because the files will have a little yellow triangle next to them containing an exclamation mark.